# Using jQuery to make content dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web app where I want to allow users to create an album by simply clicking photos and then jquery appends them to another div to represent that they are selected. My problem is how do I re-size the photo to 50px x 50px when it is in the selected div (the blue div). I am using jquery masonry so I can't have the photos just be a plain image. The images in the lower half (the ones the user selects from) need to be in parent containers named "#brick". I am at a loss, what should I do?

Here is my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/EPWSL/5/

Comment: IDs should be unique. Using #brick for everything will likely lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.photo').click(function(){

  var html = '<img class="selected-photo" src="' + $(this).find('img').attr('src') + '" />';
  $(html).appendTo('#photos');

});​
```

By the way, don't have multiple elements with the same id attribute.